# How to change build directory in QtCreator?

Tags: build, directory, cmake, qt-creator

I have a cmake based C++ project done with QtCreator. I wrote the CMakeLists.txt files manually. When building either from the command line of from QtCreator, I get this directory structure, as expected:

```
MyProj/            - source code
MyProj_build/      - object files and executable; I launch cmake from here
```

Now I would like the build directory to be on a different disk (a ram disk):

```
/PathToRamDisk/MyProj_build/
```

When building from the command line, I launch cmake/make from the new build directory, and all the generated files are located in that directory. Fine.

From QtCreator, even if I change the build path to the new one (Options/Build & Run/General/Default build directory), the build is still done in the old directory. Is there another path to change? Where?

Platform: QtCreator 3.3.0, Mac OSX

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can click the Project button on the left side of QtCreator, then you can specify the output directory. Notice, the default is for debug version, you need to specify the release version folder either.
[image: output folder]

Once you set a different folder, you will see that you need to rerun the cmake command to generate these files. This should work, I also use it on Mac.

Comment: So I changed the default build directory, leaving my project build directory unchanged. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

[Excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28765170/10251345), I just wanted to add to it a bit.  If you are using Qt Creator and want to setup your own project folder as the build directory you can use something like this.

```
%{CurrentProject:NativePath}/build/
```

I prefer this personally as it keeps everything contained in the project directory.  Other variables exist as well.

Also recently, newer versions of Qt have another little button on the right hand side of the "build directory" input field.  It is has like a blue arrow on mine.  Click it and you can view all the global build variables.

Comment: There are advantages in having the build directory separate from the project directory. It is straightforward to copy/backup your project and to configure the version control system, since you do not have to worry about excluding specific files. You can have your project on a conventional drive (permanent storage) and your build directory on a fast drive, e.g. a RAM disk, which allows to drastically reduce build times.

Comment: sure, whatever floats your boat.  I personally just like it in my project directory.  Obviously with this method you aren't required to put it in the project directory.

Answer (score 7):

You can change default build directory template By changing the *Default build directory* setting in *Options->Build & Run*.

Or directly in *~/.config/QtProject/QtCreator.ini*:

```
[...]

[Directories]
BuildDirectory.Template=.../%{JS: Util.asciify("build/%{CurrentProject:Name}/%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}")}

[...]
```