# How to re-configure a previously configured Qt Creator project?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

When loading a CMake project into Qt Creator, the project is configured using the current default settings. I want to change the default build path for existing projects. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765046/how-to-change-build-directory-in-qtcreator) describes how to change that build path, but previously configured projects are still using the previously default build path. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a project is configured by Qt Creator using CMake, a `CMakeLists.txt.user` file is created containing the previous configurations. By first removing the project from Qt Creator, and then deleting the `CMakeLists.txt.user` file, the project can be loaded using the new default settings.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem can happen with qmake projects. In that case the `<project>.pro.user` file has to be deleted.